# Magento track cart

Tags: magento

Is it possible to track the magento cart through the Form_key parameter in the #product_addtocart_form ?

Which table in the magento database holds this parameter. I need to track orders and confirm if they have been successfully paid.

Answer (score 0):

I just found all the information I need in sales_flat_order_item under product_options column